# How do I get raw request body using ASP.NET 4.0 Web Form

Tags: asp.net, rest, request

I'm trying to get the raw request body in ASP.NET 4.0 WebForm.
Request["param"], Request.Form["param"], Request.QueryString["param"] is not working.
Any idea of how to get this parameters?

[image]

```
// API POST Request with this Request Body (raw-json)
    {
      "name" : "Apple",
      "image" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg/265px-Red_Apple.jpg",
      "price" : 35
    }

// API Server trying to get request body.

// didn't work. empty
Request["name"]
// didn't work. empty
Request.Form["name"]
// didn't work. empty
Request.QueryString["name"]
```

Comment: how exactly do you post the params? from javascript? can you show your javascript-call? 
Where do you want to access the form-values? in code-behind?

Comment: @Homungus I attached image.

Comment: this doesn't look like WebForms to me :). If you want to get the values in your Request.Form, you need to put them in the form on the client side. 
in your case, as you are using postman, use the `form-data`-tab instead of the `raw`-tab and put your key-value-pairs there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Request.InputStream`

```
// include this in the top of your page to use JavaScriptSerializer and Hashtable
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections;

...
using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
    string body = sr.ReadToEnd();
    
    // Deserialize JSON to C# object
    // you can use some modern libs such as Newtonsoft JSON.NET instead as well
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Hashtable hashtable = serializer.Deserialize<Hashtable>(body);

    string name = hashtable["name"].ToString();
    string image = hashtable["image"].ToString();
    string price = hashtable["price"].ToString();

}
```